# Jhipster : where to store uploaded files?

Tags: angular, file-upload, jhipster

I'm not sure what the common way to handle uploaded pictures is. Getting the path to a directory inside the application directory can be difficult, and the entire directory could be destroyed if the WAR file is redeployed. and if I store the picture outside project how i can access it via angular in the front-end part.

So the question is, where should I store uploaded pictures to be accessible by angular ?

Comment: By default, JHipster does it in database blobs which may not scale depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the application on Tomcat, you could use its home directory with this :

```
String pathTomcatHome = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```

Then add an *uploads* folder where you would put the images.

Comment: i don't know yet what server i will be using , is there any solution for uploading into the project it self ? and the problem is not where to store the problem to store images and they will be accessible by angular in front-end